# Interop with parameters passed by ref

Tags: c#, f#, interop, mutable, ref

I'm trying to call a C# function of an already existing library (and I don't have time to port the whole library to F#)

```
namespace ExportLib
{

    public static class Xlsx
    {
        public static bool TestSave(string proposed, ref string filename, ref string save_log) {
```

from an F# code

```
let getUserFile(proposed) : UserFile =
   let mutable filename = ""
   let mutable save_log = ""
   match Xlsx.TestSave(proposed, ref filename, ref save_log) with
   | true -> FileResult(filename)
   | false -> ErrorMsg(save_log)
```

meant to transform the function into algebraic data types with the objective to make illegal states [unrepresentable](https://bugsquash.blogspot.it/2012/01/encoding-algebraic-data-types-in-c.html).

```
type UserFile =
  // The value here is the file path.
| FileResult of string
  // The value here is the error msg.
| ErrorMsg of string
```

My issue is that the `mutable` F# `filename` remains unchanged despite it is assigned in the C# function (same problem with `out string` instead of `ref string`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In F# `ref` is not a keyword but a function creating a reference cell. `Xlsx.TestSave(proposed, ref filename, ref save_log)` thus passes two newly created `ref`erence cells (pointing to `mutable string` values) into `TestSave` which in turn changes the `ref` cell to point to whatever `string` is assigned. Unfortunately, this is not observable from the outside, as there's nothing pointing to the `ref` cells. One approach is:

```
let getUserFile(proposed) : UserFile =
   let filename = ref ""
   let save_log = ref ""
   match Xlsx.TestSave(proposed, filename, save_log) with
   | true -> FileResult(!filename)
   | false -> ErrorMsg(!save_log)
```

As noted by @kvb you can also use

```
let getUserFile(proposed) : UserFile =
   let mutable filename = ""
   let mutable save_log = ""
   match Xlsx.TestSave(proposed, &filename, &save_log) with
   | true -> FileResult(filename)
   | false -> ErrorMsg(save_log)
```

and get rid of `ref`s altogether since [F# 4.0 simplified the use of `mutable`s vs. `ref`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015/).

Also, I try to avoid `match`ing on a simple `bool`, traditional `if then else` is shorter:

```
let getUserFile(proposed) : UserFile =
   let mutable filename = ""
   let mutable save_log = ""
   if Xlsx.TestSave(proposed, &filename, &save_log) then
       FileResult(filename)
   else
       ErrorMsg(save_log)
```

Obviously, [using `out` instead of `ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40681415/2894770) is even better, but for "... an already existing library ..." you might not have that choice.

Comment: That's right.  Alternatively, you should be able to keep the declarations as they were and pass references using `&filename` and `&save_log`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `out` instead of `ref` on the C# side, then you should be able to just do this instead:

```
let getUserFile(proposed) : UserFile =
    match Xlsx.TestSave proposed with
    | true, filename, _  -> FileResult(filename)
    | false, _, save_log -> ErrorMsg(save_log)
```

because trailing `out` parameters can be treated as a tuple with the actual result type.